# How can I Send message to WhatsApp Group and Sync contacts using WhatsAPI?

Tags: php, android, whatsapp

OK, I working on an application trying to send invitations to user contacts over WhatsApp   so scenario will be as follow.

- User will open invite screen.
- Screen open filled with his contacts
- Each contact marked if he is whatsapp user or not (Is it Applicable)
- when user select X from his contacts to send them invitations
- Client will send contacts details to the server
- Server will send to those contacts a whatsapp message (Is it applicable)

Note: regarding password what I understand is that password different for each user so how can I get the whatsapp password for each user using my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, getting WhatsApp password of each of your users is not feasible I think.
Because while registering WhatsApp with YOUR app, user's official WhatsApp will fail to authenticate.
If you want to send just an invite or message you can use Intent. http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

Now back to WhatsAPI,

You can send messages to group just like an ordinary message

```
WhatsProt::sendMessage($groupJID,$message);
```

To get the list of groups, you can use the

```
WhatsProt::sendGetGroups();
```

You have to bind this to an event manager like this:

```
WhatsProt::eventManager()->bind("onGetGroups", "onGetGroups");
WhatsProt::sendGetGroups();

//event manager call-back function.
function onGetGroups($phone,$groups)
{
    var_dump($groups);
}
```